# How to use "participant" vs. "participant of" correctly?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I trying to figure out the correct usage of "participant of" (P1344) and participant (P710).

As sample I want the participants of the US Civil War.
The first statement:

```
SELECT ?label WHERE {
  wd:Q8676 wdt:P710 ?subj.
  ?subj rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "en")
}
```

returns the Union & CSA.

So I tried the "reverse" Statement with participant of:

```
SELECT ?label WHERE {
  ?subj wdt:P1344 wd:Q8676.
  ?subj rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "en")
}
```

Which gives me a list of 9 names and the CSA, but not the Union.

Thus, I am a bit confused, why 1) there are several people listed, especially since I don't know any of them. (My guess those are unaffiliated ones), 2) the Union is missing, 3) how does the correct statement for participant of looks like.

Comment: I think once both properties, `p` and the inverse of `p_inv` exist, some people use one and some the other. Without reasoning you get only the asserted facts.

Comment: Regarding the data itself, I cannot say anything. I'm not a domain expert. If you want to get both asserted information, you can use SPARQL UNION or use a property paths like `p|^p_inv`. In your case `?subj wdt:P1344|^wdt:P710 wd:Q8676.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse properties aren't kept in sync, so you can find a lot of statements going in one direction without the inverse statement. Keeping inverse statements in sync was discussed [here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Requests_for_comment/Make_Symmetric_%26_Inverse_Property_addition_automatic_and_bidirectional) and there, but never done, and maybe for the better as it would be a big mess: in your example, if every participant of the [American Civil War](https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q8676) or of [WWII](https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q362) were to be added to those pages, we would potentially get very very VERY overloaded pages: using the property [conflict (P607)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P607), I found

- [2536 known participants to the American Civil War](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fsub%20%3FsubLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fsub%20wdt%3AP607%20wd%3AQ362.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)
- [31698  known participants to WWII](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fsub%20%3FsubLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fsub%20wdt%3AP607%20wd%3AQ362.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

(btw, see how you can use `SERVICE wikibase:label` to find labels instead of using filters)

So there seem to be a convention to link from the "small entity" to the "big entity", and keep properties such as [participant (P710)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P710) for especially notable entities relatively to the subject. So the Union & CSA, rather than every single known general and soliders.